# PHP global scope and variable initialization

Tags: php, scope, global, php-5.6

Simple question - I'm working with someone else's code and thus would break update-ability if I modify code outside what I'm working on. I'm just wondering in PHP if initialization is implied with the 'global' keyword inside of a function. i.e. is...

```
// some code
function myFunc() {
   global $foo;
}
// other code
```

reasonably similar to....

```
// some code
$foo = ""; // any initialization value
function myFunc() {
    global $foo;
}
// other code
```

I prefer to initialize variables in the base scope in which they are used, but as mentioned, that would require me to change the external code in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The `global` statement merely states that when the current function refers to the variable, it accesses it in the global scope rather than the local scope. It doesn't have any effect on the variable's value by itself.

In other words, it tells PHP that any reference to `$foo` within that function should be treated equivalent to `$GLOBALS['foo']`. Assigning it will assign the global variable, and reading from it will access the global variable.

Comment: OK, but I kinda guessed that much already. Are the two essentially equivalent or no? Imagine for example the $foo = "" is inside the function in the first example.

Comment: See the problem I have is this old code is ugly in that it was trying to do stuff not yet supported in php by using evals. We're in the process of removing them, but it's a big job. In this case, the part 'eval'd gets wrapped in a function call. Thus if I add an additional function and put a 'global' in it, it accesses a global scope function, but the eval'd code doesn't unless I add another global reference to the same variable. My question is if this will cause any headaches. Eventually we'll rip all that crap out, but in the meantime, I have to cope with it as best I can.

Comment: If you perform an assignment in the function, it assigns to the global variable. This will create the variable if necessary. But just having the global statement by itself doesn't create the variable.

Comment: PHP variables never get initialized automatically. If you try to access a variable that hasn't been initialized, you get a warning about using an undefined variable, but then it goes on as if it contained `null`. If you have warnings disabled, you don't notice the issue.